# Calling a method using reflection and return back the map

Tags: java, reflection, dictionary

I am trying to call a method `process` in Sample Model class using reflection in Java. That method accepts a map of string and string and returns back the same thing, a map of string and string.

Below is my code, but somehow it gives me an exception everytime.

```
Map<String, String> test = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
try {

    test.put("CGUID", "ABCD");
    test.put("RESOURCEINDEX", "XYZ");

    Method m = SampleModel.class.getDeclaredMethod("process", Map.class);
    Object o = m.invoke(null, test);

}
```

This line- `Object o = m.invoke(null, test);` gives me `Null Pointer Exception` always.

Can anyone help me what wrong I am doing here?

Below is the method signature-

```
@Override
public Map<String, String> process(final Map<String, String> attributes) {

    Map<String, String> newData = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();

    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : attributes.entrySet()) {
        StringBuilder sb =  new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(entry.getValue()).append("$$$$").append(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        newData.put(entry.getKey(), sb.toString());
    }

    return newData;
}
```

**Update:-**

```
    Class<SampleModel> consClass = SampleModel.class;
            Map<String, String> test = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
            try {

                test.put("CGUID", "ABCD");
                test.put("RESOURCEINDEX", "XYZ");

                Method m = SampleModel.class.getDeclaredMethod("process", Map.class);
                Object o = m.invoke(consClass, test);
}
```

Above code is also not working? It gives me exception as-

`object is not an instance of declaring class`

Comment: Is `m` null? What does the signature of `process` look like?

Comment: I just updated the question.. no m is not null..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method is not static, you therefore need to provide an instance when calling `invoke`.

```
SampleModel instanceOfYourClass = ...// get an instance
Object o = m.invoke(instanceOfYourClass, test);
```

You could only pass `null` to the `invoke` call if the method was `static`. Read the javadoc explaining this [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object...%29).

Comment: I updated my question with the updated code but it gives me different exception now.. Might be I am not doing the correct way..

Comment: @TrekkieTechieT-T You don't want the `Class` object of your class, you want an instance of it, something like `SampleModel instanceOfYourClass = new SampleModel()`.

Answer (score 2):

If `m.invoke(null, test)` throws `NullPointerException`, most likely the `process` method is not static.

If you don't have ability to change the signature of that method, you should pass an instance of the `SampleModel` to `m.invoke` instead of `null`.

Assuming that `SampleModel` constructor is public and has no arguments, and you don't need the instance itself for anything, like this:

```
m.invoke(new SampleModel(), test);
```